# Add a paramter to page url

Tags: urls, parameter

I have a custom page template `products`, so i get the url `site.com/products`. I want to add a parameter (for example `product`) to this url, so that I can access this page using url `site.com/products/product-1` or `site.com/products/product-2` etc.

How can I add this parameter and make that url accessible?

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to use a plugin you could use [Custom Post Type UI](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to create a "products" custom post type. Any post made inside this post type would give the permalink you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

So, adding a parameter to your url would look like this, with everything after the ? being a parameter:

```
example.com/products?product=product-1
```

But it sounds like maybe you're after using custom post types or at least a post in a category.

Say you have a CPT of "products" and a post of that type which is titled "Product 1". Your permalink would look like:

```
example.com/products/product-1
```

Or, maybe no CPT, but you do have a category named "Products" and a post under that category named "Product-2". (The caveat here is that you'd need to make sure your permalink structure supports this. In the WP admin panel, Settings >> Permalinks). Your url might look something like:

```
example.com/products/product-2
```

All of that is just to give you a little bit of context. It sounds like you're after something like a Custom Post Types plugin, or if you're into it, an ecommerce solution like WooCommerce.

It might also help to understand what a custom post type is. WordPress stores and displays contents as posts. It categorizes them as post types on your website. Even a "Page" is a type of post (a post type), in WP. Other post types that come out of the box, and that you might use without even knowing they are a post type:

- Post (Post Type: 'post')
- Page (Post Type: 'page')
- Attachment (Post Type: 'attachment')
- Revision (Post Type: 'revision')
- Navigation menu (Post Type: 'nav_menu_item')

A Custom Post Type is a custom content type. So, examples might be:

- Events
- Media
- Testimonials
- Deals
- Places
- Downloads

and in your case, Products. Every time you'd create a post in the post type Products, your url will be generated based on your permalink structure, which you set up in settings. See the [docs for more detail on choosing your structure](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#choosing-your-permalink-structure).

I hope this clarifies some things! I remember that once I wrapped my head around the idea that "everything is a post type" in WP it was a game changer. :)